# Angular-based login page for IdentityServer

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm developing a frontend app with angular and a backend with Asp.Net Core, which contains and IdentityServer4 for authentication (based on this [github project](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/Combined_AspNetIdentity_and_EntityFrameworkStorage)).

At the moment I'm logging in the IdentityServer's login page, but I want to use a custom login page developed in angular instead of using the IdentityServer's login page, instead using the login service of the AccountController.

I can call this service via http request from Angular app, but I cannot obtain the access jwt token generated by the  *_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync* function.  Is this possible? I've been searching, but I've not found a clear solution.

Answer (score 5):

You have to ask yourself something. Do you really need IdentityServer? Do you require a separate application for login?

A valid answer would be if you need it for SSO. Because you can perfectly change the whole quick start template from ASP.Net MVC to a Angular frontend and a webapi.

But I have a feeling you want to integrate your login page with your application front end. This doesn't make much sense from and OAuth view point. Because idsrv is built to be a separate application.

For example the Google login page is on a seperate domain so other applications (Like Stackoverflow) use that one to check if you are authenicated. If you would move this functionality again to the application (in this case Stackoverflow) you wouldn't have gained anything.

You can ofcourse use the PasswordCredential flow. But if you only have one application than you are probably using identity server only for the JWT generation. And you can do this more simpeler.

So can you give a little bit more information about your architecture?

(This should be a question instead of an answer but it's to long...)

Comment: A little off topic, but we are interested in an IdentityServer4 standalone app for SSO, but would like it to have an Angular UI rather than the [QuickStart UI](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI). Are you aware if this is possible (from a security perspective) and if it's been done before in a boilerplate we can build from?

Comment: @CollinBarrett I'm trying to do the exact same thing. I want to implement IdentityServer4 as an IDP/auth service, but I'd like to write a custom login UI in Angular, instead of using the Razor samples that IdentityServer provides. Were you able to do this, and do you have any sample code you could provide?

Comment: Hey @dotnetcanuck, we decided to stay with the sample .NET UI rather than going down the Angular path. Since we are using Material UI for the rest of our Angular apps, we just skinned it to look similar. I think I found somewhere on GitHub where one of the IS4 authors advised against rolling an Angular UI for it, but I can't find that comment now. Good luck!

Comment: Alright, I think I'll have to skin it like you did...I am also using Material. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: The whole answer is to convince question author not to use IS4 instead of pointing to a solution