# Restyle the UI of Abp.IdentityServer (identity server 4)

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, abp

I have created `Tiered` solution with `Angular` front-end and separated `IdentityServer` using `abp.io` framework, I have purchased a material theme for my application which I already integrated in my angular app, but IdentityServer still uses it's default UI provided by Abp, I didn't find any promising article showing the way to change it's layout design.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular application using seperate IdentityServer still uses server-side IdentityServer4 UI. Since it's serverside (Razor Pages) you can manually override Login Page. Here is an [article about how to customize login page](https://community.abp.io/articles/how-to-customize-the-login-page-for-mvc-razor-page-applications-9a40f3cd) that may help.

If you want to change the IdentityServer UI to angular, that will need lots of re-write of base code. This SO question may help, [Angular-based login page for IdentityServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539091/angular-based-login-page-for-identityserver).

Comment: Thanks @galiperdem, you answer was really helpful, one more question, how about to customize Login Page Header which title says `My Application`? and Tenants section?
Thank you in advance

Comment: @Arkadi, you can inject **Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Layout.IPageLayout PageLayout** to your razor page and then set it like `@{ PageLayout.Content.Title = "My Title"}`. I can't say I understand fully about what you mean with Tenants section.

Comment: @Arkadi It seems there PageLayout isn't working as supposed to be. We'll check it. Meanwhile you can also use as `ViewData["Title"] = "My Title"` to change the page title also.

Comment: I tried that in`.HttpApi.Host` project. but not working.. imgur.com/a/DwfjvWS 
@galiperdem
I think this is related to Tag helpers, but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @KishoreSahasranaman I couldn't follow what is not working in .HttpApi.Host. Can you create a new question about it with details if you still have the problem?

Comment: Thanks, @gterdem. I fixed it with some changes.You may find it here  https://www.diffchecker.com/LSzIPkMG

Comment: TYVM @KishoreSahasranaman You provided the missing part of the puzzle!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @gterdem answer and thanks to @KishoreSahasranaman I realized that..

This needs to be added to the Login.cshtml page so it renders fine (and works too!)

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI
@addTagHelper *, Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bootstrap
@addTagHelper *, Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.UI.Bundling
```

The documentation is kind of misleading since it sends you to do angular work when this is using IS4 on the backend